# What is wrong with this package structure in python?

Tags: python, pycharm

I have the following structure:

```
/MyApp
   /Module_A
   __init__.py
   serviceFile.py
   /Module_B
   clientFile.py
```

I am trying to call a function in ServiceFile.py from ClientFile.py

```
From MyApp.Module_a import ServiceFile
```

but I am getting the error

> ImportError: No module named MyApp.Module_a

Why?
BTW, When I run this from pyCharm it works fine only in CDM.
Both uses python 2.7

Comment: The reason this work in Pycharm is because it does some behind the scenes magic which makes sure Python is able to locate `Module_a`. If you want to run the from a terminal, you're probably going to have to mess with `sys.insert()`.

Comment: You have a lot of discrepancies in your file listing, question text, python code and python error relating to capitalization.  Python is case-sensitive.  Make sure all of those `Module_A` and `Module_a`, `serviceFile` and `ServiceFile` pairs are the same everywhere.

Comment: Is `MyApp` and `Module_B` missing an `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 2):

There's potentially 2 sources of error. The first, like @TomCho has already pointed out is if the `__init__.py` file is not properly in your modules. However, since it works in PyCharm, I'm guessing it's the second.

The second is if your `PYTHONPATH` variable is not set up properly. There are a number of places which python will by default look for modules. This includes places like the Python install directory and the current working directory. To view a full list of places which Python looks, do..

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
```

Python will then descend into each directory that has a `__init__.py` file, which is what makes that file so important. However, most likely you are not putting your code into the default places Python looks. And that's the whole purpose of the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable. You make it a list of paths where your packages are, and then those will be added to the `sys.path` seen above.

By default, `PyCharm` will add your project directory to the `PYTHONPATH`, which is why I'm guessing it worked in PyCharm, but not on the command line.

To set `PYTHONPATH` in Linux, go to the command line and type

```
export PYTHONPATH=/path/to/python/module
```

If you have more than one path you need to add, you can keep appending with `:` so the more general case is

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/path/to/python/module
```

And you can keep doing that. I typically add that line to my `~/.bashrc` file.

If you are in windows, [modifying environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7) is different, but it's still pretty easy.

Answer (score 1):

You should put a `__init__.py` file in both `MyApp` directory and `Module_B`. That makes the call `from MyApp.Module_B import clientFile` work for me. Here's my tree:

```
└── MyApp
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── Module_B
    │   ├── clientFile.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
```

By default Python won't know a certain `.py` file is part of your module if it isn't "linked" to an `__init__.py` file.